# In cmd how can I list folders that contain files with a specific extension?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

Using just the command prompt or a batch script, I would like to look inside my current directory and all subdirectories for folders containing a specific filetype.

So, example:

Say I am in directory F:\dir\one\, and F:\dir\one\ looks like this:

```
F:\dir\one\
|
+--F:\dir\one\two\
|  |
|  +--file.c
|
+--F:\dir\one\three\
|  |
|  +--work.py
|  |
|  +--F:\dir\one\three\four\
|  |  |
|  |  +--file2.c
```

And I ran my command/script looking for *.c files, I would expect an output of

```
>F:\dir\one\two
>F:\dir\one\three\four
```

because those folders contain *.c files.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be run from command line. For batch files, percent signs need to be escaped, replacing `%` with `%%`

```
for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%~fa\*.c" echo %~fa
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have a question though, what does the "~f" do?

Comment: @minseong, what `"#f"`? If you ask for `%~fa`, it is the full path to the folder being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter

Comment: If you don't want the full path (but listed under the folder) `dir c:\folder\*.c /s`. You can combine `dir c:\folder\*.c c:\folder1\*.h /b /s /a`

Comment: @Noodles, thank you. `dir /b /s` is probably the most effetive way to recursively list files AND show the full path (implicit in the combination of the two switches). But in this case the question is how to list the folders where the files are contained.

Comment: How can I use arguments that contain wildcards with this? So at the moment I have "for /r %%a in (.) do @if exist "%%~fa\%1" echo %%~fa", but it doesn't work. It treats any argument with wildcards like a normal string. How can I fix this?

Comment: @minseong, for me, inside a batch file, and passing `*.c` or any other valid expression as argument, your code works. Are you passing the argument quoted? Better replace `%1` with `%~1`, that is, the first argument unquoted. Anyway, an argument to a batch file, with or without wildcards IS a normal string. It is the command involved who interprets it as something different

Comment: @Noodles, sorry, i think you are posting your comments in the wrong question/answer. I have no problem with it, but i'm sure someone else is waiting for them.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. It's because I'd named my batch file (unknowingly) after a program that already existed in the path.

Comment: How can I list the file names as well?

Comment: @minseong, `for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%~fa\*.c" (echo %~fa % dir /b /a-d "%~fa\*.c")`, but if the files are required, it is a lot easier just `dir /s /b /a-d *.c`

Answer (score 0):

This:

> for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%~fa*.c" echo %~fa

works for current directory but it doesn't if you specify in which directory you would like to have result:

> for /r %a in ('F:\dir\one') do @if exist "%~fa*.c" echo %~fa

it just hangs. I tried 'F:\dir\one' and "F:\dir\one" and 'F:\dir\one\' and "F:\dir\one\"